# static variable Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two static variables in unity to save a certain state of my game after the avatar dies and the game reloads. here is how I define them:

```
private static PolygonCollider2D lastCameraLimit;
private static AudioClip lastSound;
```

I also use those variables for this:

```
public CinemachineConfiner confiner;
public PolygonCollider2D ColliderLevel1;
public AudioClip soundLevel1;
private static bool firstLimite = true;
```

And here is my code in the start function:

```
void Start()
{
    if (firstLimite)
    {
        // camera
        lastCameraLimit = ColliderNiveau1;
        firstLimite = false;

        //sound
        lastSound = GetComponent<GestionSonsAvatar>().PlayLevelSound(soundLevel1);
    }

    confiner.m_BoundingShape2D = lastCameraLimit;
    GetComponent<GestionSonsAvatar>().PlayLevelSound(lastSound);
}
```

The issue is that the information inside lastSound persists, but not the one inside lastCameraLimit, even if I basically did the same thing with both of them. (they are both static)

I am new to coding and unity. Thanks for your help!

I did this because I have different zones in my scene with different cinemachine confiners and I also have checkpoints. When I die and come back to a checkpoint, I want to be in the right confiner and sound for the zone I am in.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't persist? Is it getting set back to null?

Comment: yes, it gets set as it should at the begining, and when the avatar dies, it is null

Comment: Static doesn't mean it will be remembered between runs of the game.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to do with `static`.

The difference is:

- `AudioClip` is an asset that is usually<sup>[1]</sup> imported from an audio file from your disk. So the object persists unless you remove the file from the project.
- `PolygonCollider2D` is a component that should be attached to a GameObject in the scene or a Prefab in the project, anyway it can be destroyed by destroying the host object, by the `Object.Destroy` method and so on. Further reading: [Scripting concepts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingConcepts.html)

<sup>[1] An audioclip can be created on the fly, such audioclips can be destroyed at runtime.</sup>